# Plotting DataFrame Python for specific rows & Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am new to maplotlib & DataFrame.

I want to plot data from a csv file that I select from filedialog.askopenfile.
The final plan is to plot each row inside the csv file, one by one (not all at the same time), so row 1 is plotted for a few seconds, then replaced by row 2, etc.

Here's the example of what inside the csv file:

[image]

I want to plot Row 4 and 5 but only starting on column D onward.

Currently. here's the code that I have:

```
   bmFile = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r',
                                        filetypes=(("CSV file", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*.*")),
                                        title="Select a CSV file")

    bmFile2 = pd.read_csv(bmFile, header=[2])

    selectCol = bmFile2.iloc[0:,3:]
```

When I tried to plot selectCol using
`plt.plot (selectCol) plt.show()`, it plotted based on columns instead of rows (each line for each column), but I want to plot the other way around.
Here's the example of the results (fail attempt)
[image]

Could anyone please help me?
I am trying my best to write this question as english is my second language.
If it's not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default plotting is done columnwise, i.e. each column is one line. If you want to plot rowwise you can transpose the data. Pandas has its own convenience [function for plotting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot). So you can write:

```
selectCol.T.plot()
```